# Heap Buffer Overflow from a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, memory

so I am new to C programming and allocating memory. So I have written a program that does matrix multiplication. I have allocated memory for the 1d array within the 2d array for matrix 1 and same with matrix 2. Below is my code and I do not understand why I am getting a heap buffer overflow. Input contains a file that contains dimensions and components of both matrixes. An example file format might contain the following format

```
    3       3
    1       2       3
    4       5       6
    7       8       9
    3       3
    1       2       3
    4       5       6
    7       8       9
```

The first line 3 and 3 would mean 3 rows and 3 columns of matrix 1. Hence when reading it from the file it would be stored in rows1 and columns1. Next, 1-9 would be contained in the first matrix. 3 and 3 would be 3 rows of matrix 2 and 3 columns of matrix 2. Hence it would be stored in rows2 and columns2. All these numbers are separated by tabs. The above file was the one of many I tested and it got my a heap buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void print(int** square, int rows,int columns);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int rows1 = 0; int columns1 = 0; int num = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &rows1);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &columns1);

    int** square = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        square[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * columns1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns1; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
            square[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
    int rows2 = 0; int columns2; int num2 = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &rows2);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &columns2);

    int** square2 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows2);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows2; i++) {
        square2[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * columns2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns2; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &num2);
            square2[i][j] = num2;
        }
    }
    if (columns1 != rows2) {
        printf("bad-matrices\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int ans = 0;
    int** answer = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        answer[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * columns2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows2; k++) {
                ans += square[i][k] * square2[k][j];
            }
            answer[i][j] = ans;
            ans = 0; 
        }
    }
    print(answer, rows1, columns2);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void print(int** square, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", square[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Outcome:

```
==31599== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address.....
```

Comment: what is values of row2 and colums1?

Comment: @LocTran The file.txt file would be in the following format

Comment: which file? I can not see it.

Comment: make sure row2 and colums1 are equal?

Comment: @LocTran The file.txt file would be in the following format . First lines would contain the amount of rows and columns of matrix 1. Then a series of numbers that would be in the file. Then another amount of rows and column of matrix 2 and then values that belong in the second matrix. Hence row1=number of rows for matrix 1. columns 2=number of columns in matrix 2

Comment: @Nancyprogramminghelp please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_ instead of stuffing them into a comment.

Comment: @Nancyprogramminghelp, your code works fine without heap-buffer-overflow.   The result of your input sample is: 30 36 42, 66 81 96, 102 126 150, please verify if this is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

"heap-buffer-overflow" means that you created a buffer of a certain size, but tried to access beyond the bounds of the buffer.  This normally means that either you have a loop that's using the wrong value for an upper bound, or that one of your buffers is not actually the size that you think it is.

It's hard to tell for sure what's going on here.  The code copy/pasted into my gcc appears to work as expected (I don't have access to AddressSanitizer at the moment though).  The first thing I noticed about your code was that it uses values read from the input file both for buffer sizes and for loop bounds without any sort of sanity checking.  My recommendation is to step through this code in your debugger and make sure that the values that get read from disk and the computed buffer sizes are all what you expect them to be.  All it  takes is for one of those `scanf()` calls to encounter something unexpected, return zero, and throw all of your computations off.

Also, it might be useful if you include the entire output of the compiler's error message (dont' forget to compile in debug mode).  The AddressSanitizer output normally includes a stack trace that can point you to the line number where the problem occurred.  Also useful would be the name and version number of your compiler, plus whatever command-line options you're using.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `malloc`**

First, your code is fine, but that doesn't meant is doesn't contain problems. First, let's look at your use of `malloc`, e.g.

```
int** answer = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows1);
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further, and this is more style than anything else, the `'*'s` showing the levels of indirection go with the variable not the type. Why?

```
int* a, b, c;
```

That certainly does not declare 3-pointers to int. It declares a single pointer and two integers, e.g.

```
int *a, b, c;
```

When setting the type-size for the allocation, if you always use the dereferenced pointer itself, you will never get your type-size wrong, e.g.

```
int **answer = malloc (rows1 * sizeof *answer);
```

**If Allocate it, You Must Validate It, & It's Up To You to `free` it**

For every allocation, you should check that the pointer returned by `malloc, calloc, realloc` is not `NULL`. Allocation functions do fail when you run out of memory. Always check.

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Simply declare a function to free your pointer arrays, and pass each to the free function along with the row-count before your program exits, e.g.

```
void freearr (int **a, int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        free (a[i]);
    free (a);
}
```

and

```
...
fclose(fp);

freearr (square, rows1);
freearr (square2, rows2);
freearr (answer, rows1);

return 0;
```

**Why Do I Get: ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address.....?**

This is more a result of your compiler telling you to double-check your use of array bounds. Specifically here it most likely results from:

```
int answer = malloc (rows1 * sizeof *asnwer);
for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
    answer[i] = malloc (columns2 * sizeof *answer[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < rows2; k++) {
            ans += square[i][k] * square2[k][j];
        }
        answer[i][j] = ans;
```

**Note:** how `answer` is sized using the bounds of `rows1` and `columns2`, while `square` is allocated using `rows1, columns1` and `square2` with `rows2, columns2`. Your compiler can help you spot potential heap overflow by keeping track of the variables used to size the allocation. Some compilers are better than others at this.

If the compiler cannot determine that the limits you are using to iterate over your array, it can throw the warning about potential buffer overflow. (all it should care about is the value of the limits used, but like I said, some compilers are better than others...)

After allocating with the limits set out above, you then proceed to iterate over the pointer arrays with different limits that were read into separate and unrelated variables. Using `rows1, columns2` to iterate over `square, square2 & answer`. Think about it, while you know `columns1 == columns2`, then compiler has no guarantee of that. Same for `rows2 == rows1`.

Your compiler has no guarantee that using `rows1` with `square2` won't write beyond its allocated size. Likewise it has no guarantee that using `columns2` won't violate the bounds of `square`. Your test of `columns1 != rows2` doesn't provide any guarantee for `rows1 == columns2` or `rows1 == rows2`, etc...

So white all of the limits used are fine -- your compiler cannot guarantee it and warns. However, since you tediously picked though your code to know your limits are good, all it takes is a fraction of a second to confirm it, e.g.

```
 $ valgrind ./bin/read2darrq dat/arr_2-3x3.txt
==29210== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29210== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29210== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29210== Command: ./bin/read2darrq dat/arr_2-3x3.txt
==29210==
90      96      102
216     231     246
342     366     390
==29210==
==29210== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29210==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29210==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 732 bytes allocated
==29210==
==29210== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29210==
==29210== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29210== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```